# Union 2 tables to create new table but need " Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'NULL'" and how to title unmatched null columns

Tags: mysql, null, union

Here is my Union query works perfectly but my issue is when I start with "CREATE TABLE" active_emps I get error {Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'NULL'
} on NULL COLUMNS,  also all empty fields from these columns have "NULL" in them.

```
SELECT 
    sharp.Emp_Name, sharp.EmpNbr, NULL, sharp.Position, sharp.laa_CC, NULL, sharp.EmpTitle, sharp.Location
FROM
    sharp
UNION
SELECT 
    hrlist.Emp_Name, hrlist.EmpNbr, hrlist.HRnewbadge,  hrlist.Position, NULL,  hrlist.lus_CC,  hrlist.EmpTitle,  hrlist.Location
FROM
   hrlist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULL only one time as a column name and that also between the **tilt symbol** **(``)**

In your first query there are null two times that's why it shows the error:

```
{Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'NULL' }
```

Although you can but you should not use NULL as column name because its a MySQL keyword and may cause difficulty in code also.

You can use some other text as an alias for column names, Your query should be:

```
SELECT 
    sharp.Emp_Name, sharp.EmpNbr, NULL as NULL1,
    sharp.Position, sharp.laa_CC, NULL as NULL2, 
    sharp.EmpTitle, sharp.Location FROM sharp
    UNION
 SELECT
    hrlist.Emp_Name, hrlist.EmpNbr, hrlist.HRnewbadge ,
    hrlist.Position, NULL ,  hrlist.lus_CC,  
    hrlist.EmpTitle,  hrlist.Location FROM    hrlist
```